# Set-DisplayResolution isn't recognized.

Tags: powershell

When attempting to use the "Set-DisplayResolution" command in Windows PowerShell the command is not recognized on Windows 10 Enterprise edition.

This, however, should be supported as per the official documentation found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj603036(v=wps.640).aspx).

It has been attempted to run PowerShell in administrative mode as well as disabling the group policy: "Disable the Display Control Panel" found here: "User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Display"

All this resulting in the same error message:

```
PS C:\> Set-DisplayResolution
Set-DisplayResolution : The term 'Set-DisplayResolution' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script fi
le, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
 try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-DisplayResolution
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-DisplayResolution:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

A similar message is found using the related "Get-DisplayResolution" command, and neither is to be found under the modules panel in Windows PowerShell ISE.

Comment: Try using [Set-ScreenResolution](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2a631d72-206d-4036-a3f2-2e150f297515) instead.

Comment: According to https://gist.github.com/mikebranstein/59e883f970dd989d3f84afdf5e6bad80#file-screen-resolution-ps1 the command is `SetDisplayResolution` for Windows 10 IoT. Try this ...

Comment: [`Get-DisplayResolution` and `Set-DisplayResolution` are only available on Server Core](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28818028/3439404)

Answer (score 2):

According to [the MDSN documentation you linked](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj603036(v=wps.640).aspx), these commands only work with a [Server Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Core) installation:

> The Set-DisplayResolution cmdlet changes the display resolution for Windows Server® 2012 in Server Core mode.
>
> The Get-DisplayResolution cmdlet shows the display resolution for Windows Server® 2012 in Server Core mode.

Comment: Right at the top of the link it says "Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10" which probably explains the confusion ...